# Conditions equivalent to being a retract

Tags: homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold without boundary and let $N\subset M$ a submanifold (closed and without boundary).

$N$ is said to be a retract of $M$ if there exists a continous map $f:M\rightarrow N$ such that $f_{\mid_N}=id_n$.

Are there conditions on $N$ equivalent to being a retract of $M$? 
Even sufficient or necessary would be fine.

What I'm looking for are conditions related to the manifold and the complex structures not general conditions valid for any topological space.

Thank you